# I have a essage Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: parallax

The site was working fine and suddenly did stop working .

/public_html/wp-content/plugins/siteorigin-panels/inc/styles.php on line 67

Here is line 67

```
wp_localize_script( 'siteorigin-parallax', 'parallaxStyles', array(
        'parallax-mobile' => ! empty( siteorigin_panels_setting( 'parallax-mobile' ) ) ?: siteorigin_panels_setting( 'parallax-mobile' ),
        'mobile-breakpoint' => siteorigin_panels_setting( 'mobile-width' ) . 'px',
```

I'm not a programmer so don't know what to do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of PHP used on your server is lower than the required minimum of PHP 5.6.20+. Contact your hosts to request a PHP version upgrade or use your hosting control panel to upgrade the version of PHP in use. 7.3+ is recommended.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/requirements/

Comment: Thx a lot, it works upgraded to 7.4, you are amaizing !